# merging two csv using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I wanted to merge two csv files into new output file in this manner:

filea.csv:

```
A  B  C
1  a  y 
2  b   
3  f  z
```

fileb.csv

```
A B C 
1 Z c  
4 x z
6 j l
```

output.csv

```
A B C
1 a y
2 b
3 f z
4 x z
6 j l
```

hence , I retain contents of filea.csv and added '4','6' row to output.csv.
I tried pandas lib with 'isinfunction' but unable to do it .

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: Why the final `output.csv` doesn't have `Z c ` ?

Comment: i do not want to change contents of file1.csv , want to only add what is not present hence z c do not get added.

Comment: Use `pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True, sort =False).drop_duplicates(['A'])`